# How to solve mData error for Date sorting in JS Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I want to sort my date using function in table, but getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
```

This is a piece of my Table data. I have a problem with sorting date, So I create a function for sorting.

[image]

This is my JS and datatable, I use datatable purposely to display their features like search box, exporting, pagination.

JS

```
    "<table id='' class='table table-striped Layer3Table'>"+
        "<thead>"+
            "<tr>"+
                "<th class='text-center'>Activity Name</th>"+
                "<th class='text-center'>Owner</th>"+
                "<th class='text-center'>Plan Start Date</th>"+
                "<th class='text-center'>Plan Finish Date</th>"+
                "<th class='text-center'>Actual Start Date</th>"+
                "<th class='text-center'>Actual Finish Date</th>"+
            "</tr>"+
        "</thead>";
        $.each(value2.l3_task, function(key, value3){
            project += 
            "<tbody>"+
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+value3.task_name+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+value3.task_owner+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+value3.task_planned_start_date+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+value3.task_planned_end_date+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+value3.task_start_date+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+value3.task_end_date+"</td>"+
                "</tr>"+
            "</tbody>";
        });
        project +=
    "</table>"+

    // Only this 4 that I want to use sorting function.
    $('table.Layer3Table').DataTable({
        columns:[
            {data: "task_planned_start_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
            {data: "task_planned_end_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
            {data: "task_start_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
            {data: "task_end_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
        ]
    });
```

and this is my function (ISO 8601 format.)

```
    function handlerRenderDate(data, type){
        if (type === 'sort') {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/gtyow9sq/1/ example link i wrote

the reason is missing column. U need to write all columns, and in your function filter your sort. In example i imported moment.js to sort date

```
  $('table').DataTable({
        columns:[
            {Data: "task_name"},
            {Data: "task_owner"},
            {Data: "task_planned_start_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
            {Data: "task_planned_end_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
            {Data: "task_start_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
            {Data: "task_end_date", render: handlerRenderDate},
        ]
    });


  function handlerRenderDate(data, type){
              return type === 'sort' ? data : moment(data).format('DD.MM.YYYY');

    }
```

Comment: I have follow this by inserting all column equally. by this error appear. `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_11 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0`

Comment: @masteruse I edited  and put link working . I suggest u to table tbody and thead tug to html and only append your data to tbody and then initialize table

Comment: how if I am not using moment.js plugin? any other solution? I received date from DB and I massage using a function from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: yes possible u can u  data-order attribute for td   and u can parse your string to number  and write it so u dont need to use render method

Comment: maybe you can edit your answer based on this statement? :-)